# Why was this question removed?

Tags: discussion, support, deleted-questions

I lost 35 reputation from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36438489/the-auto-increment-database-automatically-add-0-id-when-the-form-fields-is-emp) which was removed for reasons of moderation.

A screenshot of the cached version of the question can be seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qk8Y6.jpg).

Even though there are similar questions on meta, just what to know why this question was deleted.

Comment: Link to the question, not a picture of the question.

Comment: @Servy Updated post, forgot about that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The user that posted the question deleted their account, and the question had a negative score so the question was automatically deleted.

The question looks like it won't ever be useful to anyone but the OP, so I see no problem with it being deleted.